# Html table within Table

Tags: html

I am trying to replicate this [image] which is a table with 3 columns, and another table with within the Average price per night column, but my i cant it get to match with my table. this is what my table looks like [image: Table2]

and this is my code. im just wondering why my columns are not looking like that,

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>        
    <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Hotels in the Key West Area</h1>
      <table  class="first">
        <tr>
         <p><th><h2>Name</h2></th>
          <th><h2>Rating</h2></th>
          <th><h2>Average Price Per Night</h2></th></p>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select ="ArrayOfHotelListItems/HotelListItems">
         <xsl:sort select="Rating" order="descending" data-type="number" />
          <tr>
            <td><p><xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/></p></td>
            <td><p><xsl:apply-templates select="Rating" /></p></td>

            <td>
              <table class="second">

                <xsl:for-each select="./Rooms/Room">


                    <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="RoomType"/> = $<xsl:value-of select="Rate"/>
                    </td>

                </xsl:for-each> 

              </table>
            </td>               
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>

    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, the styling is differen tbut the table seems to be working fine when nested.. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your issue is as it seems like you're replicating the nested table correctly... other than a few styling things.  However, looking at your HTML I would add this to make it more "proper":

```
       <table class="second">
               <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="./Rooms/Room">   
                    <td>
                     <xsl:value-of select="RoomType"/> = $<xsl:value-of select="Rate"/>
                    </td>    
                </xsl:for-each> 
               </tr>
              </table>
```

*Note the table row tags added....

Comment: yea it just styling things that needed to be fixed. nonetheless, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Ahh!  If that's the case, you can just use some CSS.  Basically you need to set the column headers to be vertical.  Also tinker with the cell bordering of your nested table.  See this article to do those things:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp